# Increase Touch Target of TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way to increase the touch target of a `TextView` without having to expand the size of the `TextView` and affecting the layout?

For Example:
If I have address information in a vertical `LinearLayout` with several `TextView`s. I make the phone number `TextView` clickable. Is there anyway to make the phone number `TextView` touch target larger without creating a padding and pushing the surrounding `TextView`s further away?

Comment: Interesting question. I know of a hacky way to do it. Override onTouch and calculate the position of the touch and see if it's close enough to the textView and then manually call it's click event :)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it with another `Layout`

Something like this, you can set the `OnClickListener` on the layout. If you want to increase the size of the touch target, just increase the height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="some text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact size of textViews you can have `FrameLayout as parent` for the TextViews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lorem ipsum" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="lorem ipsum" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="Phone number" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="lorem ipsum" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lorem ipsum" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the result you can see the touch area for the phone TextView

[image: screenshot of the rendered layout above]

Or you can get the same result when you use negative margins

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lorem ipsum" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lorem ipsum" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Phone number" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="lorem ipsum" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lorem ipsum" />
</LinearLayout>
```